# Currency exchange program in C not giving right answer

Tags: c

I am a new programmer in C. I was trying yo make a currency converter. But I am not getting the right answers. There are 4 types of currencies and each one has a number to identify them in a switch statement. It compiled without any problem. But it is returning -0.000 or something other wrong conversion.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) 
{
  int moneda_original;
  int moneda_recibida;
  float monto;
  const float peso = 0.015f;
  const float real = 0.18f;
  const float euro = 11.1f; 
  float resultado;
  printf("moneda a cambiar: ");
  scanf("%d", &moneda_original);
  printf("moneda a recibir: ");
  scanf("%d", &moneda_recibida);
  printf("monto a cambiar: ");
  scanf("%f", &monto);

/* 1: Peso, 2: Real, 3: Euro, 4: Dolar */

  switch(moneda_original)
  {
    case '1':


      switch(moneda_recibida)
      {
        case '1':
        resultado = monto;
        break;

        case '2':
        resultado =  monto / real;
        break;

        case '3':
        resultado =  monto / euro;
        break;

        case '4':
        resultado = monto * peso;
        break;
      }
      break;

    case '2':

       switch(moneda_recibida)
      {
        case '1':
        resultado =  monto / peso;
        break;

        case '2':
        resultado =  monto;
        break;

        case '3':
        resultado =  monto / euro;
        break;

        case '4':
        resultado = monto * real;
        break;
      }
      break;

    case '3':

      switch(moneda_recibida)
      {
        case '1':
        resultado =  monto / peso;
        break;

        case '2':
        resultado =  monto / real;
        break;

        case '3':
        resultado =  monto;
        break;

        case '4':
        resultado = monto * euro;
        break;
      }

      break;

    case '4':

      switch(moneda_recibida)
      {
        case '1':
        resultado =  monto * peso;
        break;

        case '2':
        resultado = monto * real;
        break;

        case '3':
        resultado =  monto * euro;
        break;

        case '4':
        resultado = monto;
      }

      break;


  }

  printf("Tu Resultado es: %.2f", resultado);
  return 0;

}
```

Comment: First thing I noticed is you're telling it to convert `moneda_original` to a number upon input (`%d`), but in your `switch` statement you're comparing it to a `char` literal, which is VERY different from a number: that is, `'1'` is not the same thing as `1`, which is probably throwing off your program. Side note: you should always have a `default` case in your `switch` to handle such things, if the input does not match any of the `case` statements.

Answer (score 1):

You are entering numbers like `1` but *comparing* with "numbers" like `'1'` (which is actually the integer representing the *character* `1`, which is `49` in ASCII).

That means none of your `switch` conditions are true, so `resultado` is not being changed.

You can confirm this by initialising it to some specific value and seeing what comes out:

```
float resultado = 2.71828f;
```

The *solution* is to change your `switch` statements to use the real values, such as:

```
case 1: // NOT '1'
```

---

You *may* also want to include `default` entries for those `switch` statements so that they generate some sort of error if the input is incorrect - that would have made the problem a lot more evident.

And another useful addition would be a prompt explaining what the different possible inputs are, something like:

```
printf("moneda a cambiar (1=Peso, 2=Real, 3=Euro, 4=Dollar): ");
```

Comment: Confusing values (like one, the number of noses you have) with representations (like '1', a digit that often represents the number one) is a common programming mistake.